# Why use causal inference if coefficients are same in an OLS?

Tags: inference, causality

I was reading this [amazing article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-fwl-theorem-or-how-to-make-all-regressions-intuitive-59f801eb3299) about FWL theorem and it's application to causal inference.

In the article, there are some examples showing that the coefficients of an OLS estimator is the same when estimating the coefficients using the FWL theorem.  If that's the case, what is the point of using causal inference to reduce multivariate regressions into univariate ones?

The article mentions couple of reasons, but if the coefficient in question is the same for both approaches I'm having difficulty seeing the benefits of it. TIA!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Causal inference is all about what to estimate, not about how to estimate it

The point of causal inference is not to reduce multivariate regressions into univariate ones. The point of causal inference is to identify **what** estimand to estimate to begin with.
The article in question gives you multiple ways of running the same regression. That's great, but how would one know what regression to run in the first place? That's the question causal graphical models help answer, and it's also how it's used in the article you cited.
Without the causal graph shown in their example, we would not know what to include in our regression model, and the FWL theorem could not help us. Once we are given the causal graph, we know what we would like to estimate and we can then use different techniques (e.g. FWL) to do so.